# PDF.JS Preview large pdf file (> 200MB) on client side, that was sent from server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, pdf.js

I'm working with a pdf viewer, that will load a pdf file from server (nodejs) and then rendering on client side to allow user reading direct in my site.

I'm using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to rendering pdf file on client side. The problem is client side must download entire pdf file before they can parse and render it, so if the file is too large (~200MB in my case), user must wait for download entire 200MB.

I researched and i think i can solve this problem by 2 ways:

- Split the large pdf file into many smaller pdf files on the server side, and serve only specific small file on-demand. But this way, i will lost some important metadata like the pdf outlines,...
- Using pdf.js direct in server side, get the pdf pages and then serve each page as binary to client side, client side will also use pdf.js (addPage function) to add each page to their viewer. But i don't know it is possible or not.

So what should i do to solve this problem?
Thank you so much.

Comment: were you able to make changes on server side to render pdf with range request? even i am trying to do the same i have made changes on server side, Pdf.js make call to the server as expected but it does not make for all ranges. Please let me know what changes are needed to be done on server side i am using spring boot. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes i was solved this problem by update server to support range request and then pdf.js worked excellent. i didn't change anything on client side. I'm using nodejs on server side

Comment: Additionally, i was failed when manual implement range request on server side, so i tried to use a library (https://github.com/pillarjs/send), so you can refer code of that library to see what need to be change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to optimize all your PDF files for web.

The default settings of `pdf.js` will load only the portion it needs to render.

See [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#range) for more info.

Comment: Ah, i didn't know pdf.js support range request, i will try it, thank you so much!